# Image resize keeps repeating itself

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a fairly simple web page, having a banner image
and a simple animation (marquee emulation). I want to have a responsive image
in the page. The problem is that whenever the animation loop iterates, the image resize repeats itself.

```css
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: marquee 17s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: marquee 17s linear infinite;
  background-color: red;
}
    
.marquee:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
     
.fixed-ratio-resize{
  height:auto;
  max-width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<img src="image.png" class="fixed-ratio-resize" alt="banner" />  

<p class="marquee">
   Do not use marquee tag for improve accessibility and readability.
</p>
```

I would like to "disengage" the animation from the image resize, ie to have the image resized only when the viewport is changed. 
MTIA

Comment: you can use `width` instead of `max-width`

Answer (score 0):

If you need responsive image then you have to follow this code on your fixed-ratio-resize css. you can set width:90% if you want.

```
.fixed-ratio-resize {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is an example with marquee emulation. With 90% of image width. If you have any question ask me in comment.

```css
 @keyframes marquee {
    0%   { text-indent: 430px }
    100% { text-indent: -485px }
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
    0%   { text-indent: 430px }
    100% { text-indent: -485px }
}
 .marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: marquee 17s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: marquee 17s linear infinite;
  background-color: red;
}

.marquee:hover {
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.fixed-ratio-resize {
  height: auto;
  width: 90%; /*YOU CAN USE 100% if you want */
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
    <img src="http://orig10.deviantart.net/f6bf/f/2007/054/1/9/website_banner_landscape_by_kandiart.jpg" class="fixed-ratio-resize" alt="banner ">
<p class="marquee">Do not use marquee tag for improve accessibility and readability.</p>
```